# angularjs get value from input in recursive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

How'd I get the value to controller from a nested view? I'd like to mention that I have a recursive approach.

**HTML**

```
<textarea ng-model="inputValue" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched"></textarea>
```

[Full HTML structure can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/q4y41pkn/2/)

**Edit:**
I want to get the value of the textarea in my controller. (e.g. $scope.inputValue ); currently getting undefined

Comment: Could you clarify the question? What do you want?

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I want to get the value of the textarea in my controller. (e.g. $scope.inputValue );

Comment: This is just the HTML structure AFTER rendering by Angular. To understand the problem it would be far easier to have a working plunkr with the javascript files including the directives.

Having said this, if you are using recursive or nested templates from directives you might want to look into these two pages

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346373/angularjs-objects-inside-nested-directives-getting-undefined

http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this jszfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/7qbucc62/

```
 <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="firstController">
        <textarea ng-model="inputValue"></textarea>
        <textarea ng-model="inputValue"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    (function abc()
    {
        var app=angular.module("app",[]);
        app.controller("firstController",function($scope)
        {
            $scope.inputValue="";

        });
    })();
</script>
```

I think this is what you are asking

you can use $scope.inputValue directly in your controller. It will provide you the value of textarea